# What can i select pairs of products in Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

Orders table

[image]

There is an orders table, where user_id is the user id, item_id is the id of the ordered product. It is necessary to obtain a sample of pairs of goods ordered by different users, namely the following result:

Result Table

[image]

I can not understand how to do this? Thanks guys

Comment: What is the logic behind that

Comment: What you want to do exactly ?

Comment: You are going to have to explain much better what you want to do if you want someone to write your code for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to to get a list of product pairs (2 products) that have been ordered by multiple customers, then

1. Create a list of product pairs by customer by self joining your table on itself (inner subqueries)
2. Join this list on itself again, but for different customers (outer query)

I would create the following query:

```
select distinct
    (select t1.user_id, t1.item_id as item_id1, t2.item_id as item_id2
     from table t1
     inner join table t2 on t1.user_id=t2.userid and t1.item_id<t2.item_id) l1
inner join
    (select t1.user_id, t1.item_id as item_id1, t2.item_id as item_id2
     from table t1
     inner join table t2 on t1.user_id=t2.userid and t1.item_id<t2.item_id) l2
     on l1.user_id<>l2.user_id and l1.item_id1=l2.item_id1 and l1.item_id2=l2.item_id2
```

The `t1.item_id<t2.item_id` join condition will ensure that a particular product pair is retrieved only once, so you will have `3, 4`, but not `4, 3`, also it excludes pairing products with themselves, so you will not have `3, 3`.

Comment: Oh thank you. I kind of understood. But still difficult for me. Thanks again, you helped me out. You are awesome!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without subqueries (well, assuming you have an `items` table):

```
select i1.item_id, i2.item_id, count(*)
from items i1 join
     items i2
     on i1.item_id < i2.item_id join
     orders o1
     on o1.item_id = i1.item_id join
     orders o2
     on o2.item_id = i2.item_id and
        o2.order_id = o1.order_id
group by i1.item_id, i2.item_id
having count(*) > 1;
```

The join between `i1` and `i2` generates a list of all pairs of items, with the first item smaller than the second (prevents duplicates).

The join to `o1` brings in the order id for the first item.

The join to `o2` brings in the order id for the second item -- and ensures that the order id is the same as for the first item.

The `group by` counts the number of orders that have both items.

And the `having` clause ensures that there are at least two.